# the text in slider becomes bold and thick in ie

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, slider

I use wp-accordion slider in one of our client web site. It looks great in most of the browsers, but when it comes to IE, the font in the slider title becomes very bold and thick. This happens only in IE.

The following is the css part that is used to display the tex in the slider that I use.

```
#accordion p.css-vertical-text {
border: 0 solid red;
bottom: 30px;
color: #333333;
display: block;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 18px;
height: 205px;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
white-space: nowrap;
width: 220px;
}
```

The slider displays the content through loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the IE rendering by giving a background color to the element, try for example:

```
background-color: white;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a font-weight to your declaration :

```
#accordion p.css-vertical-text {
    border: 0 solid red;
    bottom: 30px;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:400; /* add this */
    height: 205px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: is already there but IE is not picking it up. Thank you Sorry missed few lines the actual code is as follows.                                      p.css-vertical-text {
    color:#333;
 border:0px solid red;
 white-space:nowrap;
 
 display:block;
 bottom:30PX;
 width:220px;
 height:205px;
 font-family: Helvetica Neue Light;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:normal;
  // text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
 filter: flipv fliph;
}

Comment: bottom:30PX    ???  capital ?? Will you give FULL html + css code or we will have to guess and waiste our time 'guessing' what you're doing in order to try to help you ?

Comment: @akkarthe Have a look to my answer.